# How to replace dataframe-element with another dataframe-element

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

DataFrame I have prepared is as follows...

| Index and Title | Index |
| --- | --- |
| 1 aa aa aaaa | 1 |
| 1.2 bb bbbb bb bbbb bb b | 1.2 |
| 1.2.3 ccc cc c ccccc cccccc | 1.2.3 |
| 2 dddd d d dd ddd | 2 |

DataFrame I want is as follow..

| Index and Title | Index | Title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 aa aa aaaa | 1 | aa aa aaaa |
| 1.2 bb bbbb bb bbbb bb b | 1.2 | bb bbbb bb bbbb bb b |
| 1.2.3 ccc cc c ccccc cccccc | 1.2.3 | ccc cc c ccccc cccccc |
| 2 dddd d d dd ddd | 2 | dddd d d dd ddd |

I tried it with a following code

```
df['Title'] = df['Index and Title'].str.replace(df['Index'] + ' ','')
```

However, the debugger said ...

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

How should I do in this case?

Answer (score 2):

```
df["Title"] = df["Index and Title"].str.split(n=0).str[1:].str.join(" ")
```

```
>>> df
               Index and Title  Index                  Title
0                 1 aa aa aaaa      1             aa aa aaaa
1     1.2 bb bbbb bb bbbb bb b    1.2   bb bbbb bb bbbb bb b
2  1.2.3 ccc cc c ccccc cccccc  1.2.3  ccc cc c ccccc cccccc
3            2 dddd d d dd ddd      2        dddd d d dd ddd
```

Comment: I'm very sorry that my explanation is too short.
'Title' includes SPACEs as above modified table.

Comment: Don't worry about that. I fixed my answer

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples only, this could be taken care by [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) function of Pandas, please try following.

```
df["Title"] = df["Index and Title"].str.extract(r'^\d+(?:(?:\.\d+){1,})?\s+(\D+)$', expand=True)
```

OR in case you may have digits after later values then try following:

```
df["Title"] = df["Index and Title"].str.extract(r'^\d+(?:(?:\.\d+){1,})?\s+(.*)$', expand=True)
```

Output of `df` will be as follows:

```
               Index and Title  Index                  Title
0                 1 aa aa aaaa      1             aa aa aaaa
1     1.2 bb bbbb bb bbbb bb b    1.2   bb bbbb bb bbbb bb b
2  1.2.3 ccc cc c ccccc cccccc  1.2.3  ccc cc c ccccc cccccc
3            2 dddd d d dd ddd      2        dddd d d dd ddd
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
^\d+(?:(?:\.\d+){1,})?  ##Matching starting digits in column Index and Title, digits may followed by dot and digits(1 or more occurrences) keeping this optional.
\s+                     ##Matching 1 or more occurrences of spaces here.
(\D+)$                  ##Creating 1st capturing group which has all non digits values till end of value.
```

Answer (score 0):

If need `replace` by both columns use lambda function with `axis=1`:

```
df['Title'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Index and Title'].replace(x['Index'],''), axis=1).str.strip()
```

If need only letters with spaces (there is no replace by `Index` column) use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df['Title'] = df['Index and Title'].str.extract('([a-zA-Z ]+)', expand=False).str.strip()
```

Comment: I'm very sorry that my explanation is too short.
'Title' includes SPACEs as above modified table.

Comment: @aaaaa0a - Both solutions should working well.